# Design Compiler - Join and Meet type

Tags: types, compiler-construction, typechecking, type-systems

I am using SML to design a compiler for another functional language (you can see its definition here http://corelab.postech.ac.kr/~hanjun/2016S_compiler/hw/fun_language_definition.php). My task is to design a typechecking. 
What is return type?
`if a>0 then <<3, 4>, 5> else <<6>, 7, 8>`

For answering this question, I need to find "join" of the 2 type above. "Join": is the least common supertype. For example, `t1 <: t3` and `t2 <: t3 => t3` is a `join(t1,t2)`.
"Meet" is most common subtype. `t3 <: t1` and `t3 <: t2 => t3` is a `meet(t1, t2)`.

My task to design meet and join mutually recursive. 
Could you please give me a hint how to implement them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to study the sub-typing rules to deduce the recursive definition.  For an example, use tuple types.  Since longer tuples are subtypes of shorter ones, given that the common prefix types match, and one tuple type is a subtype of anther if the element types are pairwise sub-types, you'll have:

```
join(<t1, ... tm>, <u1, ... un>) = <join(t1,u1), ... join(tp,up)>
    where p = min(m,n)
```

and

```
meet(<t1, ... tm>, <u1, ... un>) = <meet(t1,u1), ... meet(tm,um), u_m+1, ... un> 
    when (wlog) m <= n
```

Most of the rules will be self-recursive like this. The exception will be function types due to parameter inversion. Here you'll need meet to define join and vice-versa. I won't spoil your fun by giving the answer.

The base cases are of course just

```
meet(int, int) = join(int, int) = int
```

Comment: what do you mean for (wlog)?

Comment: @hminle  Sorry. That's "without loss of generality,"meaning that if you have m > n, you can just reverse the operands.

Comment: Hi Gene, one thing more, what do you mean by "given that the common prefix types match"?

Comment: @hminle Just that. It's what the 4th subtyping rule says.

Comment: Hi Gene, could you tell me a little bit about how to find join of ref type? Is 
`join(t1 ref, t2 ref) = t1` ?

Comment: Oh, `join(t1 ref, t2 ref) = meet(t1 ref, t2 ref) = t1` is true if and only if `t1 ref <: t2 ref`